# Synchronously retrieve a random number of record IDs, change button text and Asynchronously retrieve the corresponding records from the "server"

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I need to change the text and style of the "Get next" button to "Loading...", 
Synchronously retrieve a random number of record IDs from a "server" and Asynchronously retrieve the corresponding records from the "server", only proceeding when all records have been received.
Sort the records in date order, oldest first and at the end reset the button to its original state

**The code is as follows**

```
let loading = true;

const buttonHandler = function () {
  loading = !loading;
  toggleButton(loading);
  getRecords();
};

const btn = document.getElementById('get-records');
btn.addEventListener('click', buttonHandler);

function toggleButton(loaded) {
  btn.innerHTML = loaded ? 'Loading...' : 'Get next';
  btn.classList.toggle('button-not-loading');
  btn.classList.toggle('button-loading');
}

function getRecords() {

  // getting the IDs of the records to fetch is a synchronous operation
  // you don't need to change this call, it should return the IDs
  const ids = Server.getIds();
  const allTheRecords = [];

  // getting each corresponding record is an async operation
  ids.forEach(function (recordId) {
    Server.getRecord(recordId, function (error, data) {
      // if the fetch is unsuccessful the callback function is invoked with the error only
      // if the fetch is successful the callback is invoked with error variable set to null,
      // and data variable will hold the response (i.e. the record you wanted to retrieve)

      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        error = null;
        allTheRecords.push(data);
      }
    });

    // you can get a SINGLE record by calling Server.getRecord(recordId, callbackFunction)
    // callbackFunction takes 2 parameters, error and data
    // invocation as follows

    // you need to make sure the list is not rendered until we have the records...
    //but need to allow for any fetch errors or app will hang
    // i.e. a record you request might not exist - how would you allow for this?
    // when you have the records, call processRecords as follows

    processRecords(allTheRecords);
  });
}

function processRecords(records) {

  toggleButton(true);
  const sortedRecords = sortRecords(records);
  let html = '';
  let tr;
  sortedRecords.forEach(function (index, value, array) {
    tr = '';
    tr +=
      '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + value.date + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + value.name + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + value.natInsNumber + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + value.hoursWorked + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + value.hourlyRate + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + (value.hoursWorked * value.hourlyRate) + '</td>' +
      '</tr>';
    html += tr;
  });

  document.getElementById('results-body').innerHTML = html;
  addTotals(sortedRecords);
}

function sortRecords(records) {

  let sorted = records.sort(function (a, b) {
    return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
  });

  // sort results in date order, most recent last

  return sorted;
}

function addTotals(records) {

  let hours = 0;
  let paid = 0;

  records.forEach(function (value, index) {
    hours += value.hoursWorked;
    paid += (value.hoursWorked * value.hourlyRate);
  });

  document.getElementById('totals-annot').innerHTML = 'TOTALS';
  document.getElementById('totals-hours').innerHTML = hours;
  document.getElementById('totals-paid').innerHTML = paid;
}
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

there is no question there, but ill give a vague pseudo code answer which should be enough to point you in the right direction. 
Keyword = Promise.

```
const loadRecordIds = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        jQuery.get('http://localhost/recordIds').then((data) => {
            // do something with the data ... e.g parse/validate
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
};
const loadRecords = (recordIds) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        jQuery.get('http://localhost/records?recordIds='+recordIds).then((data) => {
            // check the data for errors etc
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
};
const toggleButton = () => {
    // toggle your button styles
};

// and you use the functions in sequence using .then() or async keyword(if you have a preprocessor or dont care about old browsers)

loadRecordIds().then((recordIds) => {
    // now you have your recordIds loaded
    toggleButton();
    loadRecords(recordIds).then((records) => {
        // now you have your records available for further processing
    });
});

// with async await keywords you could do the same like this.
try {
    const recordIds = await loadRecordIds();
    toggleButton();
    const records = await loadRecords(recordIds);
} catch (error) {
    // handle errors
}
```

If you dont know what promises are, google them.

// ok, ill throw in a quick sample of an async code that runs in "sync" using promises.

```
step1 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // time has run out now, and its time for the second step
            // calling "resolve" will call the "then" function and allows the code to continue
            // whatever you pass in as the argument for resolve() will be a parameter in the "then()" function callback.
            resolve('3000 seconds has passed, time to continue.');
        }, 3000);
    });
};
step2 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('2000 seconds has passed, time to continue.');
        }, 2000);
    });
};
step1().then((message) => {
  console.log(message);
    step2().then((message) => {
        console.log(message);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('and now the script is done...all in sequence');
        }, 2000);
    });
});
/*
this will output
3000 seconds has passed, time to continue.
2000 seconds has passed, time to continue.
and now the script is done...all in sequence
*/
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I've watched a video about promises a long time ago, and didn't understand it to be true. Thank you again, I will google more about it

Comment: I added a simple example to the answer. If you want to run async code in sequence then you put that code inside a promise. Whenever the async code has finished its job(e.g a timer ran out, or server sent a response) then you call "resolve()" which will trigger the "then()" part of the code.